# JSDoc support in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, jsdoc

Is there documentation for what [JSDoc](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagReference) subset, superset, or mix of the two IntelliJ supports? My motivation for using JSDoc is two-fold:

1. For developers: so IntelliJ can provide better code-completion, code checking, error checking, etc.
2. For runtime efficiency: using the [Closure compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler.html).

For #1 above, it is important for me to use JSDoc markup that is supported by IntelliJ, and until now figuring this out has mostly been a trial and error process.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on what little information is available in the [WebStorm documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/javascript-and-ajax.html), it looks like IntelliJ IDEA supports the entire JSDoc set. The only other note in the documentation is on [viewing inline documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/viewing-inline-documentation.html) which only points at the [JSDoc SourceForge page](http://jsdoc.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 7):

It's been a bit trial and error, but I have finally been able to get decent results with it. I had especially trouble with getting inheritance for Backbone similar OO to work right. What I ended up doing was things like this:

```
/**
 * @class App.Views.ProductView
 * @extends App.Views.TemplateView
 **/
App.Views.ProductView = App.Views.TemplateView.extend(
  /** @lends App.Views.ProductView **/
  {  
      /**
       * @param {string} str
       * @return string[]
       **/
      method: function (str) {
           return [str, str];
     }
  };
```

You definitely have to help out a lot manually when inheritance is involved.

As far as I can tell, discrepancies were: you *have* to provide a name to @class, else it gets confused. @name seems to not work really well. The rest is decent, some of the tags are unused (@event, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

The JSDoc support by IDEA / WebStorm is a standard feature nowadays, but with some IDE tuning it's possible to generate a JSDoc with one click.

The step-by-step guide how to enable a JSDoc generation in IDEA / WebStorm with the `jsdoc` npm module:
[How to generate JSDoc documentation in IntelliJ IDEA / WebStorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64069426/how-to-generate-a-jsdoc-in-intellij-idea-webstorm)