# How to generate a JSDoc documentation in IDEA / WebStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jsdoc

Is it possible to generate a JSDoc documentation in IDEA / WebStorm with one click, just like I do JavaDoc with IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TL;DR:

[image]

### To add a functionality of the JSDoc documentation generation to IntelliJ IDEA / WebStorm:

1. Install `jsdoc` to the Node.js project: `npm i jsdoc`
2. Prepare a JSDoc configuration file (`jsdoc.json`) and store it in the root of the project
3. Go to **File | Settings | Tools | External Tools** in IntelliJ IDEA / WebStorm
4. Add a new external tool called **Generate JSDoc…** of group **Documentation**.
5. In **Tool Settings** provide the following parameters:

   - **Program**: path to the Node.js binary, e.g.: `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe`
   - **Arguments**: path to JSDoc scripts and to the JSDoc config (`jsdoc.json`), e.g.: `$ProjectFileDir$/node_modules/jsdoc/jsdoc.js -c $ProjectFileDir$/jsdoc.json`
     Here it is possible either specify absolute paths or provide a relative path using IDE's internal command `$ProjectFileDir$`
   - **Working directory**: path to the sources, e.g.: `$ProjectFileDir$\src`
6. Press **OK** and **Apply**

Now, go to **Tools → Documentation → Generate JSDoc…**, et voilà, the JSDoc is generated and stored according to the JSDoc config (`jsdoc.json`).

P.S. This guide is tested on IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.